# Google Chart with Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization

I am using two (or more) Google charts in a page with Bootstrap tabs. Depending on my tab navigation, the chart lose the size going for a default(?) size. Bellow is a reduced test case with a step to see the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/73o0rfqe/

How to reproduce:

**Situation #1:**

- Click **Two** tab. The chart resizes to the actual size only after the tab click. I am looking for a way render it after page loads (before the tab click).

**Situation #2:**

- Click **Two** tab, click **TwoC** tab, click **One** tab, click **Two** tab, click **TwoA** tab. Now the chart loses the actual size. Click **One** tab, click **Two** tab. Now the chart renders with the actual size again.

This part of the code:

```
$("a[href='#One']").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
    clearChart();
});
```

I am using to try this, but it is not working like it should. Any help will the helpful.

PS.: Any suggestion on optimizing this code will the helpful too. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies in that you redraw your chart with

```
$("a[href='#One']").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
    clearChart();
});
```

when you change around with tabs. I have no clue why it draws with incorrect size when you do it the way you wrote, but I've never worked with bootstrap.

(as a side note, I don't see why you load the google package on tab changes, this causes a lot of loads from googles servers. Something like

```
$("a[href='#One']").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    drawChart();
});
```

would be enough.)

A solution is to render both charts on page load and then being done with them, check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/pwh4j1m6/1/) and you'll see it works.

Comment: @joun check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43402896/5090771)...

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly the problem I was having. It helped me solve the problem of drawing Google charts in tab-content navigator

Answer (score 8):

While implementing the `charts`, `graphs` inside the `tabs`, the content resize issue may occur.

**Reason for this type of issue**

In Bootstrap tab, while we switching tabs only the active tab will have the property `display: block;` rest of the `tab-contents` are applied to `display: none;`.

This is the major cause of this issue if the div element has a property `display: none;`, there the **width** is also considered as **0px**.

To override this issue I have added the following **CSS**, Instead of hiding the tabs by using `display: none;`, I handled with **height** & **overflow** property by this method the width will not set to **0px**.

---

### CSS

```
.tab-content>.tab-pane {
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
 visibility: hidden;
}
.tab-content>.active {
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

I have forked your code from you jsfiddle link give in the question (https://jsfiddle.net/73o0rfqe/).

Here is the link which having the updated code(i.e, just only added the above-given CSS )

https://jsfiddle.net/swasatz/28qttaqb/2/

Check out fiddle hope this may helpful for you

Thanks.

Note: This is one of the methods to resolve this issue using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a CSS problem. This is the solution that worked for the problem that I was having, loading charts into hidden tabs:

```
.tab-content > .tab-pane,
.pill-content > .pill-pane {
    display: block;     
    height: 0;          
    overflow-y: hidden; 
}

.tab-content > .active,
.pill-content > .active {
    height: auto;       
}
```

Comment: Explain your answer