# Issue with displaying Google Chart in a bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, charts, google-visualization

I have an issue with displaying a Google Chart in a Boostrap tab.
I have two tabs, and a Google Chart in each. In the first one, the chart is correctly displayed, but in the second one, the chart is tiny and compressed.
I don't understand why..

Here is my code :

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="player">
    <h3>Players' resources</h3>
    <div id="totalPlayerChart" style="height: 500px;"></div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="producer">
    <h3>Producers' resources</h3>
    <div id="totalProducerChart" style="height: 500px;"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTotalPlayerChart);
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTotalProducerChart);

    function drawTotalPlayerChart() {
        [...]
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('totalPlayerChart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function drawTotalProducerChart() {
        [...]
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('totalProducerChart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the result of drawing a chart while it's container is hidden,
when there are no specific size settings in the options

to correct the issue, add specific size, or wait until the tab is visible before drawing the chart...

also, `setOnLoadCallback` only needs to be called once per page load

it can also be placed in the `load` statement

recommend setup *similar* to the following snippet...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        switch ($(e.target).html()) {
          case 'Players':
            drawTotalPlayerChart();
            break;

          case 'Producers':
            drawTotalProducerChart();
            break;
        }
    });

    function drawTotalPlayerChart() {
      [...]
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('totalPlayerChart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function drawTotalProducerChart() {
      [...]
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('totalProducerChart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    // draw chart on initial tab
    drawTotalPlayerChart();
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

Comment: I have also gone through one option, to resolve using CSS. Could you please give me your opinion/Feedbacks about my approach!!!

Answer (score 8):

While implementing the `charts`, `graphs` inside the `tabs`, the content resize issue may occur.

**Reason for this type of issue**

In Bootstrap tab, while we switching tabs only the active tab will have the property `display: block;` rest of the `tab-contents` are applied to `display: none;`.

This is the major cause of this issue if the div element has a property `display: none;`, there the **width** is also considered as **0px**.

To override this issue I have added the following **CSS**, Instead of hiding the tabs by using `display: none;`, I handled with **height** & **overflow** property by this method the width will not set to **0px**.

---

### CSS

```
.tab-content>.tab-pane {
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
 visibility: hidden;
}
.tab-content>.active {
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Thanks.

Note: This is one of the methods to resolve this issue using CSS.