# Google Chart not displaying correctly in Chart Area

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, google-visualization

Actually, I am facing related to the Google charts while implementing with Dynamic data. Here the issue When ever I am clicking a tab that particular data has to be displayed in Chart.Suppose Say like Clicking the current Day is displaying the below result in chart[image]

After pressing on the tab say after pressing Last week it is not displaying chart correctly in chart area
[image]

Suppose if u press again Current Day the char is displayed like this 
[image]

Here the chart area is not working properly after having first click and second click

```
`google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });

$('#t1').click(function () {
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(BarC);
    function BarC() {

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: xxxx.xxxx.xxxx,

            dataType: 'json',

        }).done(function (results) {

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'data1');
            data.addColumn('number', 'data2');
            data.addColumn('number', 'data3');
            data.addColumn('number', 'data4');

            data.addRows(results.length);
            for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                data.setValue(i, 0, results[i]["data1"]);
                data.setValue(i, 1, parseInt(results[i]["data2"]));
                data.setValue(i, 2, parseInt(results[i]["data3"]));
                data.setValue(i, 3, parseInt(results[i]["data4]));
            }

            var options = {

                backgroundColor: 'transparent',

                bars: 'vertical',
                chartArea: { left: 0, top: 0, width: '100%', height: '100%' }// Required for Material Bar Charts.
            };

            var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart'));
           chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
        }
        );
    }

});`
```

Comment: need to wait until the chart's container is visible before drawing the chart. check the answer here --> [Issue with displaying Google Chart in a bootstrap tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43401936/5090771)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {

  $('#t1').click(function () {
    // ...
  });

  $('#t2').click(function () {
    // ...
  });

  // ...

});
```

https://embed.plnkr.co/19CellQvdGZTjzf9hikU/

Comment: i have total 16 tabs so for each like i need to give ?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: actualy i created bootstrap carousel and in each slide of carousel i have 4 tabs . slide 1 -4 tabs,slide 2-4 tabs,slide 3-4tabs,slide4-4tabs and in each tabs im displaying the chart