# Positioning Google Charts inside Bootstrap tabs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-visualization

I created Bootstrap3 tabs `RES` and `BUS`. In each of these two tabs I want to position two Google charts (Area and Pie carts). So inside bootstrab `tab-pane` I put bootstrap row and split it into columns `col-sm-9` (for larger AreaChart) and `col-sm-3` (for smaller PieChart).

Identical content is inside both BUS and RES tabs! but position on second (RES) tab is ruined. WHY? And how to fix it?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="thumbnail">
          
          <h3>Title</h3>

<hr>

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li class="active"><a  data-toggle="tab" href="#BUS">Bus</a></li>
              <li><a  data-toggle="tab" href="#RES">Res</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
              <div id="BUS" class="tab-pane active">
              
                <div class="row">
                  <h3>BUS title</h3>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div id="AreaB1"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div id="PieB1"></div>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- .row -->

      <script type="text/javascript">

        function drawChartsB()
        {
          var view;

          var AreaOpt = {
            height: 200,
            legend: { position: 'bottom', maxLines: 1 },
          };

          var PieOpt = {
            height: 200,
            legend: { position: 'bottom', maxLines: 1 }
          };

          view = new google.visualization.DataView(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['X','A','B'],['2017M02',95,0],['2017M03',129,0],['2017M04',42,33]]));
          view.setColumns([0,1,{sourceColumn:1,role:"annotation"},2,{sourceColumn:2,role:"annotation"}]);
          (new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('AreaB1'))).draw(view,AreaOpt);

          view = new google.visualization.DataView(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['X','AB'],['A',42],['B',33]]));
          (new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('PieB1'))).draw(view,PieOpt);
        }

        </script>   
 
              </div>
              <div id="RES" class="tab-pane">

                <div class="row">
                  <h3>RES title</h3>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div id="AreaR1"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div id="PieR1"></div>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- .row -->  
                
      <script type="text/javascript">

        function drawChartsR()
        {
          var view;

          var AreaOpt = {
            height: 200,
            legend: { position: 'bottom', maxLines: 1 },
          };

          var PieOpt = {
            height: 200,
            legend: { position: 'bottom', maxLines: 1 }
          };

          view = new google.visualization.DataView(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['X','A','B'],['2017M02',95,0],['2017M03',129,0],['2017M04',42,33]]));
          view.setColumns([0,1,{sourceColumn:1,role:"annotation"},2,{sourceColumn:2,role:"annotation"}]);
          (new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('AreaR1'))).draw(view,AreaOpt);

          view = new google.visualization.DataView(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['X','AB'],['A',42],['B',33]]));
          (new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('PieR1'))).draw(view,PieOpt);
        }

        </script>
        
              </div>
            </div><!-- .tab-content -->
    
          </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
        </div><!-- .col -->

      </div><!-- .row -->
      
    </div><!-- .container -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

      google.charts.load("current",{callback:drawChartsB,packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.load("current",{callback:drawChartsR,packages:["corechart"]});

    </script>
```

External JSFiddle: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/sbrbot/rkh909w1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to wait until container is visible before drawing the chart,
or need to set specific size settings in the chart options...

also, recommend calling the `load` statement only once...

try setup similar to following...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row text-center">

    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="thumbnail">

      <h3>Title</h3>

      <hr>

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a  data-toggle="tab" href="#BUS">Bus</a></li>
          <li><a  data-toggle="tab" href="#RES">Res</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div id="BUS" class="tab-pane active">

            <div class="row">
              <h3>BUS title</h3>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div id="AreaB1"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div id="PieB1"></div>
              </div>
            </div><!-- .row -->

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function drawChartsB()
    {
      var view;

      var AreaOpt = {
        height: 200,
        legend: { position: 'bottom', maxLines: 1 },
      };

      var PieOpt = {
        height: 200,
        legend: { position: 'bottom', maxLines: 1 }
      };

      view = new google.visualization.DataView(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['X','A','B'],['2017M02',95,0],['2017M03',129,0],['2017M04',42,33]]));
      view.setColumns([0,1,{sourceColumn:1,role:"annotation"},2,{sourceColumn:2,role:"annotation"}]);
      (new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('AreaB1'))).draw(view,AreaOpt);

      view = new google.visualization.DataView(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['X','AB'],['A',42],['B',33]]));
      (new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('PieB1'))).draw(view,PieOpt);
    }

    </script>   

          </div>
          <div id="RES" class="tab-pane">

            <div class="row">
              <h3>RES title</h3>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div id="AreaR1"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div id="PieR1"></div>
              </div>
            </div><!-- .row -->  

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function drawChartsR()
    {
      var view;

      var AreaOpt = {
        height: 200,
        legend: { position: 'bottom', maxLines: 1 },
      };

      var PieOpt = {
        height: 200,
        legend: { position: 'bottom', maxLines: 1 }
      };

      view = new google.visualization.DataView(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['X','A','B'],['2017M02',95,0],['2017M03',129,0],['2017M04',42,33]]));
      view.setColumns([0,1,{sourceColumn:1,role:"annotation"},2,{sourceColumn:2,role:"annotation"}]);
      (new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('AreaR1'))).draw(view,AreaOpt);

      view = new google.visualization.DataView(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['X','AB'],['A',42],['B',33]]));
      (new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('PieR1'))).draw(view,PieOpt);
    }

    </script>

          </div>
        </div><!-- .tab-content -->

      </div><!-- .thumbnail -->
    </div><!-- .col -->

  </div><!-- .row -->

</div><!-- .container -->

<script type="text/javascript">

  google.charts.load("current",{callback:drawChartsB,packages:["corechart"]});

  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      switch ($(e.target).html()) {
        case 'Bus':
          drawChartsB();
          break;

        case 'Res':
          drawChartsR();
          break;
      }
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Thx for effort, but nope, this does not help. My real page and functionality is more complex than shown here. I use AJAX to asyncly fill the tab panes with more graphs (8 per tab). Here is just excerpt and result of AJAX showing the needed. AJAX works fine and it fulfills panes corectly, loader is loaded in advance. That0s all fine. The point of my Q is that the same content on one pane does not look the samo on another pane!!! Please look at the snippet or code on JSFiddle.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand you. My AJAX call fetches the data from DB, dynamically creates script for charts, sends content with filled scripts to my page into tab panes. Upon successful response from AJAX it runs Google Chart loader with callback function to show my charts. After loading google component it starts function to show chart. (That's the AJAX-Google-chart chaining). From my snippet one can see that charts are shown and Google API did it's own job. The problem is with layout of these charts on tab-panes.

Comment: the chart container for tab _Res_ is hidden until clicked, if you draw a chart in a hidden container the layout gets messed up, need to wait until the tab is shown before drawing the chart for the first time -- or hard code all the size settings to prevent -- [here is another example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43401936/5090771)

Comment: OK, now I understand. Google Chart dynamically takes the size of its parent container in order to calculate its own dimensions before rendering. So, one has to define (hardcode) dimensions through options (I don't want this because then it will not be responsive) or show tab and then start rendering. But your suggestion helped me to implement another solution. Loading charts on tab only when needed (when someone clicks on tab). I already use this approach for some other things (data in tables not charts). Really don't know why I didn't use this approach here as well. However, you helped.

Comment: Excellent. You just saved me quite a headache. I can confirm that the container does indeed need to be visible and not just available to the DOM. As soon as I displayed my tab in Bootstrap (after loading my chart HTML via AJAX) and made it visible and _then_ executed the rendering of my chart the UI looked perfect. If I did it after the DOM was loaded, but before displayed, it looks all weird.